# Importing GraphQL resolvers and schema triggers error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

When I am trying to run server with following configuration I receive an error:

> Error: "createUser" defined in resolvers, but has invalid value "function (userInput) {...
> The resolver's value must be of type object.

index.ts

```
const schema = loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, './schema/**.graphql'), {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()]
})

const schemaWithResolvers = addResolversToSchema({
  schema,
  resolvers: {
    ...UserResolvers
  }
})
```

.graphql schema

```
# import User, UserInput from "User.graphql"

type RootQueries {
  user(id: String!): User
}

type RootMutations {
  createUser(userInput: UserInput): User
}

schema {
  query: RootQueries
  mutation: RootMutations
}
```

resolvers

```
const UserResolvers = {
  async createUser(userInput: UserInput) {
    // some code
  }
}

export { UserResolvers }
```

Comment: What `addResolversToSchema` function are you using?

Comment: @Bergi it is a function from graphql-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
const schemaWithResolvers = addResolversToSchema({
  schema,
  resolvers: {
    RootMutations: UserResolvers
  }
})
```

as resolvers are usually grouped by the type they appear on.

Comment: it helped but now my userInput param in createUser resolver is undefined

Comment: @Sheppard25 Your `createUser` function doesn't match the [expected resolver signature](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/resolvers/#resolver-function-signature), but the first argument should never be `undefined`.

Comment: Yep, I see it was changes in graphql-tools. The first argument is undefined probably because I do not use rootValues property